# Getting Jedis error while trying to connect from VM to GCP cloudmemorystore

Tags: redis, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

I am trying to connect on GCP memorystore from teh same VM . But getting

{"timestamp":"2018-07-26T20:02:48.127+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Error connecting to Jedis pool","path":"/ds/initiate"} , when i am trying to connect redis directly from VM it is connected and can PING and PONG , so redis is connected . but i am getting the above error. When in install redis locally on VM and then run the application , the application works just fine, but not when i try connecting from same VM to memorystore ip , please help

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig;

@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/ds")
public class ControllerMain {

@GetMapping("/initiate")
public void checkhe(HttpServletRequest req , HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

    try {
          JedisPool jedisPool = (JedisPool) req.getServletContext().getAttribute("jedisPool");

          if (jedisPool == null) {
            throw new SocketException("Error connecting to Jedis pool");
          }
          Long visits;

          try (Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource()) {
            visits = jedis.incr("visits");
          }

          resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
          resp.getWriter().println("Visitor counter: " + String.valueOf(visits));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage());
        }
}



private Properties config = new Properties();

private JedisPool createJedisPool() throws IOException {
  String host;
  Integer port;
  config.load(
      Thread.currentThread()
          .getContextClassLoader()
          .getResourceAsStream("application.properties"));
  host = config.getProperty("redis.host");
  port = Integer.valueOf(config.getProperty("redis.port", "6379"));

  JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
  // Default : 8, consider how many concurrent connections into Redis you will need under load
  poolConfig.setMaxTotal(128);

  return new JedisPool(poolConfig, host, port);
}

}
```

Comment: Hi Himanshu, few clarifying questions: 
1) Is the VM where you are hosting above code (which tries to connect to memorystore redis) in the same region as your memorystore instance? 
2) Also are you saying that you were successfully able to connect to memorystore redis instance from VM and execute PING/PONG command ?

Comment: yes the vm is in the same region , and i can connect to redis and do ping and receive pong.

Comment: Hmm, few more questions just to make sure you are not hitting any corner cases. 
1) How are you deploying the application? Is it being hosted on AppEngine?
2) Are you passing host configuration to Jedis?

Comment: deploying on a standalone VM on GCP connected to memorystore. If i deploy a redis locally on the same VM , it is working fine ... but when i put the memorystore ip it shows error . but i can PING and PON with the same memorystore ip

Comment: Thanks for the details. Right now based on the information we have, it does seem like an issue with Jedis configuration. In order to dig deeper we would require more information like projectId.
Hence would you be able to create a support case (https://cloud.google.com/support/) or create a post in this group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-memorystore-discuss) ?

Comment: According to the information you have shared, as suggested before, I recommend filing a ticket in the Public Issue Tracker [1]. This is due to the fact that your application will need further investigation and project information is required to dig into this particular issue. [1] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers